# Xamarin.UITest :: How to Tap over an specific word inside a paragraph?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I need help with a test that I'm writing for to upload it into Xamarin Test Cloud.
Do you know if there is a way to detect a specific word coordinates? I mean, the developer team has merged a URL inside a paragraph, and I need to Tap over the URL, like for example, the paragraph is "...hello to [everybody](http://#), from my new workstation...", and the URL is embedded only in "everybody" word, so I need to Tap over that specific word in order to go to that URL.

- Is this possible to do?
- Is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you resolved this?

As a potential workaround, have you tried

```
app.Tap(c=>c.Property("text").Contains("everybody"))
```

Would it be possible if you provided a screenshot from the tree command in the REPL console?

Comment: Hi @Lemons, your approach is not valid because you are tapping over a test area and nothing will happen unless the link word will be exactly at the place where you are doing the tap, and the link place will change in every device depending resolution and orientation. I've made an ugly approach tapping each 30 or 50 points inside the text area, until find the embedded link. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm having the same issue where its not tapping at the exact coordinates of the substring